# Knockoutjs Unwrapping ko.observableArray recursively

Tags: knockout.js

I have javascript array in this format:

```
omega.franchiseInfo.rawdata = [{
                Id: "Main",
                Title: "Main",
                Type: "main",
                items: [{
                    Id: "Menu1",
                    Title: "Menu1",
                    Type: "menu",
                    items: [{
                        Id: "Menu1",
                        Title: "Menu1",
                        Type: "menu",
                        items: []
                    }]
                }]
            }];
```

Every item has a property items which is an array containing other items. The number of elements of the array is not specified.

I am using the knockout mapping plugin on the array to make it observableArray. And all the members of the array also become observables.

```
omega.franchiseInfo.observableRawData = ko.mapping.fromJS(language.rawdata);
```

What I want to accomplish is then unwrap the `omega.franchiseInfo.observableRawData` to become in its original pure javascript format. That means to be equal to `omega.franchiseInfo.rawdata`. I know that there are methods in knockout like `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` but javascript is not my strong side and I couldn't make it work for my case. Also I think that the function that will do the job should be recursive to go through all the items in the array.

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/931/

I will be very greatfull if somebody can help me with that and provide a working code. Thank You for your time and effort.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/P7KUC/)

You can convert it back to JavaScript object like this :

```
ko.toJS(omega.franchiseInfo.observableRawData);
```